# Hide/Show element on mouseover/out using jquery

Tags: jquery

On a page there are multiple elements like this

```
<h1 class="bodyText hide">1</h1>
<h1 class="bodyText hide">2</h1>
<h1 class="bodyText hide">3</h1>
```

and

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}

.bodyText {

}
```

Now when mouse enteres the bodyText element the text should fade in and out when mouse leaves the element. What I tried:

```
$('.bodyText').on('mouseover', function(event){
    $(this).fadeIn();
});

$('.bodyText').on('mouseout', function(event){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

This does absolutely nothing. Any ideas how to do this?

I want to achieve this kind of effect: http://www.google.com/intl/de/about/datacenters/gallery/index.html#/

Comment: how come do you plan to `hover` a hidden element?

Comment: try wrapping each `<h1>` elements in a visible container and apply the mouse in/out event to those wrappers fadding in/out the child `<h1>`. Just beware of bubbling ... use hoverintent plugin so solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `<h1>` elements are hidden they can't trigger the `mouseover` event - your mouse can't hover an element that is not present.

You should have them visible and hide/show a child element.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/na5zQ/1/)

Comment: added a simple fiddle just to illustrate it :)

Answer (score 1):

and one more way to do it.

```
$("#DivMain").hover(
    function(){
        $(".DivSub").show();
    },
    function(){
        $(".DivSub").hide();
    }
);
```